# Grid style in app.xaml makes content invisible

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, styles, wpf-grid

I want to define a grid style in the app.xaml, including the background color.
However, setting the color there, makes the whole content instantly invisible.

[image]

When application is executed, the following appears:

[image]

For a short moment, the button is visible. 
How do I prevent this from happening, keeping in mind, that I wish a global background color for grids.

Comment: I just found another nearly same question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205414/my-wpf-ui-disappears-when-i-set-a-style-for-grid-in-app-xaml but answer is not really solving what is meant to achive

Comment: Do you really want to set global style for the grids? This mean, that it will be applied nearly everywhere, since `Grid` being used almost in each control template. Would be a work around, posted as comment in linked post, a solution for you?

Comment: I want to, as I want to make everything in kind of dark style, and switching between themes is morst easy over app.xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a global style for the `Grid` as you have done it.

The issue you have faced comes from Visual Studio. So the issue is only present, if you start the application via Visual Studio.

To give the possibility for live tracking of UI-Elements the VS seems to add an `AdornerLayerWindow`, which, I suppose, also uses a `Grid`, which you see.  You can find this window in `Application.Current.Windows`.

To get rid of this behaviour you have to **deactivate** option ***Options->Debugging->UI-Tools for XAML activate***